# Don't work Push to Stack in C#

Tags: c#, stack

For my Stack I use:

```
private Stack stOperations = new Stack();
```

So, when Stack constains only one element (Stack[0] = "false" (this is string)) and I try to push using:

```
stOperations.Push(neededIDs.Contains(element) ? "true" : "false");
```

Where `neededIDs.Contains(element)` = false.. nothing happens. Stack doesnt change! I know that because I see that in VS debugger:

[image: stack in debugger]

Explain me, please, where am I wrong?

Comment: this code works over here perfectly fine. How did you determine that the stack doesn't contain two elements after the push?

Comment: are you using System.Collections.Stack? You'd be better off using System.Collections.Generic.Stack anyway...

Comment: @EliArbel i attached a screenshot

Comment: @Axarydax hmm.. in my using-section System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic. explain, why second is better than first? Why should not I use Stack() and must use Stack<T>()?

Comment: stOperations still contains "false" in your case @IgorAdamenko

Comment: @Aniket I know. So, if stack contains any value I cannot push it again?

Comment: @IgorAdamenko - if you know your stack will contain only strings, then  Stack<String> will provide `void Push(string)` and `string Pop()` methods. If you use the non-generic Stack, you'll have to cast the result as it has `object Pop()` method.

Comment: @IgorAdamenko - see this sample: http://ideone.com/fJqxCD - what's different from yours?

Comment: @Axarydax not different, I have same code.
so, when I add «Console.WriteLine(stOperations.Count) it's output right count values. I think, VS was working wrong..

thank you!

P.S.: And I will use Stack<string>, yes :)

Comment: @IgorAdamenko you may want to check the watch/local on `.Count` *after* executing the line that pushes the value. The screenshot you show is the situation *before* you push the value.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I mean that I see values in debugger, no more. And I know that I must check values after executing code that changes them. Nonetheless, thank you for participating in the discussion :)

Answer (score -1):

do this instead:

```
neededIDs.Contains(element)? stOperations.Push("true"):stOperations.Push("false");
```

Comment: I dislike this style, as I think that ternary operator should be used to return a value, not to do side-effects

Comment: @Axarydax hmm, I use this style because it clearly tells what I am trying to do

Comment: I understand, but I think that Igor's original code: `stack.Push(expression ? "true" : "false")` is clearer as you are pushing something in both cases, just the value changes.

Comment: -1 since it doesn't answer the question, and is controversial, style or personal preference based.